# How to get a list of all loaded libraries in dart?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Is it possible to make some call from main to get all the loaded libraries at runtime?

```dart
main(){
  Iterable<LibraryMirror> libraries = getAllLoadedLibraries();
}
```

I see there is a Type LibraryMirror in the mirrors package but I don't see how you would get a library mirror since you can't just reference them in code like a top level function/variable or class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors`;

currentMirrorSystem().libraries;
```

Comment: dart:mirrors are deprecated: https://github.com/google/reflectable.dart/issues/98